# vs code alters jsx when saving .js file

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I am trying to learn some React and I have a js file, client.js. I have a class inside the file that is very simple and just trying to return one line. I am using Visual Studio Code.

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
render() {
    return ( 
        <h1>Hello World!!</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

However, every time I save the file in VS Code, it alters the jsx line to what follows.

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( <
            h1 > Hello World!! < /h1>
        );
    }
}
```

I can save it in notepad and things like that but not in VS Code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: take a look to [react-beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=taichi.react-beautify)

Comment: Hi there. Please disable all unwanted extensions installed in VSCode. These extensions sometimes mess the code formatting. 
Update to latest VSCode.

Webstorm is also a great IDE for JavaScript Apps. It supports JSX and React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update to latest version of VS Code and try to rename the file to jsx instead of js. VS Code works fine with jsx files

Comment: Naming the file .jsx did work for me. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 7):

There's a toggle now on the bottom right side of the editor which can be used to switch Language Mode (for an open .js file, click on Javascript, type in "react" and choose Javascript React), but this must be done for each file individually. However, you get to keep your files as .js.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Beautify extension then disable it. 
It would work fine.